How to calculate the amplitude value of emitted signal when generating a radar signal for matched filtering?
In the matched filter process, two signals are used: one is the emitted (reference) signal, and the other is the signal that has reflected off the target and has noise added to it. I calculate the amplitude of the reflected signal using Blake's radar equation.

I find Pr (Power received) form Blake's radar eq. and take its square root and multiply it by the signal.

So, what should the amplitude of the reference signal be? In the examples I've seen, the operations seem to be independent of the radar's power. Could it be that the amplitude value of the reference signal used in the matched filter process is always assumed to be 1? If so why?

I'm using convolution theorem for matched filter process. And sending OutputSignal to CFAR.


OutputSignal = convolution(referenceSignal, receivedSignal);


It's amplitude doesn't matter unless you are trying to calibrate to something like RCS. What matters in 99.99% of cases is the signal-to-noise ratio.
